# Async/Await func doesn't wait to console.log it's response

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, axios

I am trying to make an asynchronous function and save it's response to a variable, then console.log that variable, but it is console.logging the response before the asynchronous function finishes.

```
import axios from 'axios';

async function getItems() {
  const response = await axios.get(SOME_URL);
  console.log('done', response);
  return response;
}

const items = getItems();
console.log('items: ', items);
```

I would expect the logs to look like this:

```
// Expected result
done: {...result...}
items: {...items...}
```

But what I actually get is this:

```
// ACTUAL result
items: Promise {<pending>}
done: {...result...}
```

I want to wait until the request is complete to continue on below my call to `getItems`.

What am I missing?

Comment: you should await `getItems` if you want to wait for the results

Comment: `const items = await getItems()` or use `then()`

Comment: Using async/await doesn't magically make asynchronous behaviour synchronous. It's really just syntactic sugar for a function returning a promise; you still need to deal with that promise when you call the function, either by calling it from another async function or chaining thens.

Answer (score 7):

Since "`getItems`" is async call so you will get the result in ".then" like below

```
import axios from 'axios';

async function getItems() {
  const response = await axios.get(SOME_URL);
  console.log('done', response);
  return response;
}

getItems().then(items => console.log('items: ', items))
```

Comment: Also, if you want to handle the execption inside your getItems() function, you can also do a try {} catch(error){} inside the function and then just call getItems() , be sure that you wrap your try block with the await function inside. Remember that is always important to catch errors in asynchronous process